# Problem installing @angular-redux/store in Angular application

Tags: angular, redux

I'm new into Angular development and learning how to use Redux. While trying to install Redux using `npm install redux @angular-redux/store --save`, the terminal throws up the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^7.0.0" from @angular-redux/store@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-redux/store
npm ERR!   @angular-redux/store@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T07_15_27_253Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried installing **redux** and **@angular-redux/store** separately. That way, while **redux** is getting installed successfully, **@angular-redux/store** still throws up the same error. I tried checking for solutions, but in most forums, `npm install redux @angular-redux/store --save` is the recommended command to install them. Even [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-redux/store) and the official sites say so.

Even after force install, I can't use `import { NgReduxModule, NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';` in **app.module.ts**, neither can I access `NgReduxModule` and `NgRedux` in the `imports` array of **app.module.ts**.

So what's wrong with my system? How do I get rid of the errors and can install Redux successfully? Please help as I'm new into it and finding it difficult to figure it out.

My development environment trivia:

- Node: 18.12.1
- Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
- Angular CLI: 14.2.10
- Angular: 14.2.12
- OS: Windows 10 win32 x64

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`@angular-redux/store` hasn't been updated in years and doesn't specify that it supports the latest Angular 15 version, which NPM considers as an error. This can be ignored using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, but Angular's official library support only includes libraries that are built no longer than 2 majors ago (so Angular 15 requires libraries that have been built using Angular 13+).

Hence, I opted to go with NgRx. I managed to install NgRx and learn the fundamentals of how to use it from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P5DTlg9oLc&list=PLkGg-M9IbfttjGlG98qid7ctH5wkbVZ65&index=35) tutorial. Now my basic concepts of State, Action, Reducer and Store are clear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Redux with Angular. Rely on RxJS features instead.

Ref:
[https://www.stackchief.com/blog/Why you should NEVER use Redux with Angular](https://www.stackchief.com/blog/Why%20you%20should%20NEVER%20use%20Redux%20with%20Angular)

**TL;DR**

Redux was popularized with React and used to simplify data and state sharing between components. Angular (as an opinionated framework) can achieve this natively based on RxJS subscribe features and dependency injection. Redux does not add anything of value for Angular, it just adds more boilerplate.

As more and more people realized this, I assume support for Angular-Redux libraries stopped.